# How to bind two WPF combo boxes to a single XML file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, xaml, data-binding

I have the following XML file:

```
<Palettes>
  <Palette>
    <Primary Name="Black"/>
    <Other Name="Blue"/>
    <Other Name="Red"/>
  </Palette>
  <Palette>
    <Primary Name="Green"/>
    <Other Name="Orange"/>
    <Other Name="Yellow"/>
    <Other Name="Violet"/>
  </Palette>
</Palettes>
```

I want to have two combo boxes: One which displays the primary colors of each palette, and another which displays the “Other” colors of the palette selected in the first combo.

I would like to have this data binding done in the XAML file and not in the code-behind, if this is possible.

I have the following XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="80" Width="350">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="Palettes" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Palettes.xml" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbxPrimary"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Primary/@Name"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Palettes}, XPath=/Palettes/Palette}"
                  Margin="10,10,175,10"
                  SelectedIndex="0"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbxOther"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Other/@Name"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cbxPrimary, Mode=OneWay, Path=SelectedItem}"
                  Margin="175,10,10,10"
                  SelectedIndex="0"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding XPath=./Other/@Name}"
                  SelectedValuePath="./Other/@Name"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

However, this will show blank entries for the “Other” colors in the second combo box:

[image: Blank combo box]

I cannot figure out whether I am missing something, or if this is coded improperly. How can this be corrected?

Comment: You can drop the `OneWay` on those bindings, `ItemsSource` is pretty much always one-way (you cannot modify it with a simple `ComboBox`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the name of `DisplayMemberPath` implies it is a path to a member, not arbitrarily nested nodes or attributes. I would change the bindings as follows:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxOther"
          DataContext="{Binding ElementName=cbxPrimary, Path=SelectedItem}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=./Other/@Name}"
          Margin="175,10,10,10"
          SelectedIndex="0"/>
```

Using `SelectedValue`/`Path` and `DisplayMemberPath` only makes sense when the display should be different from the underlying value.